# Handling failed testcases using testng

Tags: testng, listeners

I have implemented ItestListeners and IRetryAnalyser and IAnnotationTransformer for rerunning failure test cases.

When a test fails iam expecting onfailure method to execute first and then iannotationtransformer to handle retry later. but first iannotationtransformer is being called and itest listener is treating the test as failed. is there any change we can over come this without treating the test as skippd after failure.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the `IAnnotationTransformer`?

Answer (score 0):

`IAnnotationTransformer` is used to modify annotations before TestNG read them.

And the first step of a TestNG run is to read annotations from classes.

So the seen behavior is the expected one.

Comment: is there any chance that we can override it. I want my testng annotation to be triggered first so that testng listener will not treat failed test as skipped once. Suggest me a better failure tests rerun if that you know.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand your problem

Comment: OK. Here is what I am doing and what am facing.
I have three classes which implement ItestListener, IRetryAnalyser and IAnnotationTransformer. 
Whenever a test fails I want to re-run the same since I have IannoataitonTransformer which executes before in results I am seeing the test as both skipped and failed. Is there any chance where I can retry the test without using iAnnotationTransformer. so that iTestListener will listen to the failure and rerun it using IRetryAnalyser.

Comment: `IRetryAnalyser` alone is enough to rerun failed test. That's why I don't understand the `ITestListener`/`IAnnotationTransformer` part.